# How do HR departments generally decide how many of your hours are for teaching?

Tags: united-kingdom, lecturer

I know how many hours I am paid for each week but have recently been asked to do a bit more teaching and told that, based upon what I was already doing, they were allowed to ask me to do a bit more.

So it seems they have a way of figuring this out. Perhaps even rules about it. I didn't know this. Are there standard rules? I know the work week is theoretically 36 hours so I wonder how much of that is assigned to teaching according to HR departments?

I might just ask them, but I don't know if they'll tell me. It all seems very much like they are making the rules as they go, or at least moving the goalposts depending on the specifics of the situation.

Thoughts?

Comment: If the university is reputable they have established policies. Otherwise... I guess you are on your own.

Comment: They seem to have policies, but I have no idea what they are, and nobody in my department seems sure either...

Comment: It is probably an all-university policy. HR should be able to resolve it.

Comment: Is there a union?

Comment: There is a union. Are they the best people to ask? They are a little busy at the moment, so perhaps I'll see what they say in a few weeks. I don't want to complain about anything. I just want to get a sense of what the rules are, and at what point I could start to question my workload.

Comment: I've asked HR. They might give me an answer. They might also say to ask head of dept, who will then say to ask HR, and around we will go.

Comment: You should ask someone as soon as possible. When would the new teaching duties start? If you find that you do not have to do them, you want to give the Head time to make other arrangements.

Comment: I'm already doing the extra. I do have to do them. I just now want to know if I can be asked to do more or if this is it. What's the maximum, so I know what to expect in future years, rather than be surprised like I have been now.

Comment: I can only speak for the US. In the US, for TA or RA, the maximum working hour per week is 20 hour as a part-time position for most universities. Even if we all know that as a PhD research assistant, the time you spend on your project is definitely more than 20 hour/week, but you wouldn't get more salary.

Answer (score 1):

Most UK universities will have something they call the "workload allocation model (WAM)" or "work allocation framework (WAF)" or something similar. At least in theory these are supposed to ensure you have a fair amount of work allocated. In general, the aim is to either a) ensure the hours officially allocated to tasks you have to perform are within your contracted hour (averaged across the year) or b) that everyone in the dept has a comparable allocation.

They generally either have an hourly allocation per task, or a points based system (to draw attention away from the total amount of work allocated and focus on fair sharing between faculty members).

So, for example, I get 3 hours allocated for every 1 hour lecture, 20 minutes for each exam script i mark, 5 hours for every 3 hour practical, 72hrs a year per PhD student, 120 per postdoc I supervise, 120 hours for the committees I'm on, etc.

These are sometimes a bit of a joke, as no one i know has anything less than 120% of their time allocated.

Its worth noting that while the WAM can in theory be used to examine the balance of teaching, research and service for one person, it is primarily targeted at balancing total workload between individuals.

I also second what solar mike said - this is primarily the job of your HoD, and HR likely have nothing to do with it.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest talking to your head of dept or equivalent as HR usually have little experience of teaching, the preparation necessary or the effort involved in marking...

So department head or equivalent as they should know exactly what you are expected to do at the moment and what the increase is.

Comment: It is my head that asked me to do more, and they were the one who told me they had spoken with HR to check this was valid. I just want to know the facts of what the maximum amount of hours I can be asked to do is. I'd like to have no more surprises, or at least know that they might be coming.

Comment: HR tell me they have no policy regarding this, and that I should talk to my HoD. So what this seems to mean is what I am asked to do depends on who the HoD is and the amount of students we have that year.

Comment: The more students, the bigger the workload. But no change in salary. This just makes we want to make my classes less appealing, interesting enough that they keep running, but not so interesting that a lot of people sign up.

Answer (score 0):

This is going to be institution-dependent. For example, [CCSU says in section 10.2](https://csuaaup.org/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/CSU-AAUP-BOR-Contract_Indexed-and-TOC-1.pdf):

> The instructional load for full-time teaching members shall be twelve
> (12) load credits per semester in Connecticut State University. Except
> where otherwise provided in this Agreement one (1) hour of classroom
> activity (including lecture and laboratory) equals one (1) load
> credit. Existing courses with more than one (1) load credit per class
> hour will remain unchanged. The department and appropriate university
> curriculum committee may establish higher load credits for courses.